# Pygame detects collision at Spawn, despite no existing collisions

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

I'm working on a skeleton of an rpg, using Sprites for collision detection.  However, upon spawn, pygame is printing out that there are collisions when in fact there are none:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.draw import rect as square

winWidth = 800
winHeight = 800
black = (0, 0, 0)

everything = pygame.sprite.Group()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((winWidth,winHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('RPG Skeleton with Classes')


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.display = gameDisplay
        green = (0,255,0)

        self.xchange = 0
        self.ychange = 0

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

        self.x += self.xchange
        self.y += self.ychange

        self.color = green
        self.player = square(self.display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
        self.add(Players)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.x, self.y])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def draw(self):
        self.x += self.xchange
        self.y += self.ychange

        self.player = square(self.display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
        #self.image = pygame.Surface([self.x, self.y])
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #self.rect = self.get_rect()

        #self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

        #if self.rect.colliderect(walls.rect):
        #   print "Collision"

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #super(Wall, self).__init__()
        self.display = gameDisplay
        grey = (119, 136, 153)

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.add(Walls)

        self.color = grey
        self.player = square(self.display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
        #self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.x, self.y])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        self.wall = square(self.display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
        #self.image = pygame.Surface([self.x, self.y])
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

wallWidth = winWidth * .4
wallHeight = winWidth * .4
Players = pygame.sprite.Group()
Walls = pygame.sprite.Group()

link = Player(winWidth / 2 - 50, winHeight / 2 - 50, 50, 50)
wall1 = Wall(0, 0, wallWidth, wallHeight)
wall2 = Wall(winWidth - wallWidth, 0, wallWidth, wallHeight)
wall3 = Wall(0,winHeight - wallHeight, wallWidth, wallHeight)
wall4 = Wall(winWidth - wallWidth, winHeight - wallHeight, wallWidth, wallHeight)

pygame.init()


def main():




    pygame.display.update()

    run = True
    while run:


        gameDisplay.fill(black)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_k:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                    link.ychange = -5
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                    link.ychange = 5
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                    link.xchange = -5
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                    link.xchange = 5


            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                    link.ychange = 0
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                    link.ychange = 0
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                    link.xchange = 0
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                    link.xchange = 0




#       link.draw()
        # wall1.draw()
        # wall2.draw()
        # wall3.draw()
        # wall4.draw()

        hitWalls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(Players, Walls, False, False)

        for collision in hitWalls:
            print "collision"

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

If anyone is able to offer any feedback or assistance, it is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could find the problem with the collision is because the "wall4" size is fills most of the display, including the player. From 0,0 to 480,480 and as the player its at 380,380 its colliding.

You can find this out by simply printing out the details of the sprites. With this simple code:

```
for wall in Walls.sprites():
    print(wall.rect)
```

and this for the Players:

```
for player in Players.sprites():
    print(player.rect)
```

There you can see that the 4 wall occupies most of the display and the position of the player on the next one.

Walls OutPut:

```
 <rect(0, 0, 0, 480)>
 <rect(0, 0, 0, 0)>
 <rect(0, 0, 480, 0)>
 <rect(0, 0, 480, 480)>
```

Players OutPut:

```
 <rect(0, 0, 350, 350)>
```

Now to fix it, change the walls size and coordinates, and ready!

Sorry I can give you more help if you need more, I don't really touch sprites that often to know more.